# Cannot apply css style for kendo-checkbox inside a kendo-treeview

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a

My problem is that the CSS for k-treeview is applied from scss file but it is not applied for the kendo-checkbox

i tried

```
<kendo-treeview
        [nodes]="tcHolderProducts"
        class="productTree"
        [textField]="'text'"
        kendoTreeViewCheckable
        kendoTreeViewExpandable
        kendoTreeViewSelectable
        [(checkedKeys)]="checkedKeys"
        [children]="children"
        [hasChildren]="hasChildren"
      >
      </kendo-treeview>
and my css is :

  .k-treeview {
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    kendo-checkbox {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
```

already many classes used but without any help

Comment: can you please show some code and/or stackblitz project where we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your scss in the global `style.scss` file.

Answer (score 0):

add before styling this :
::ng-deep .productTree {
}
and it will work to make the styling in your own UI component